# Python + Convert UTC time (in seconds) into local time, when latitude and longitude are known

Tags: python-3.x

[image]I have a 2D matrix, "time_utc_sec" (dimensions: [latitude, longitude]). "time_utc_sec" is the time in seconds when a satellite passed over each spatial (lat,lon) grid box since its launch. The satellite was launched 2011-10-12 at 00:00:00.000 (UTC time).

I would like to convert these "time_utc_sec" to local times (Gregorian calendar) for each spatial grid box. How can I do this?

I have searched for solutions, but not quite found an example which solves my task. Does anybody have an efficient way of doing this, preferably with a python function?

I included an example of "time_utc_sec" below, which is taken for 8 March 2014 around 6 am UTC as well as the satellite trajectory.

```
lat = np.arange(-5.5, 6.5, 1)*(-1)     # 5.5 N  to  5.5 S
lon = np.arange(250.5, 256.5, 1)       # 110.5 W  to  106.5 W

time_utc_sec
array([[ 75883956.83706953,  75883974.05996561,  75883991.2259402 ,
         75884008.31080523,  75884025.38669217,  75884042.55329135],
       [ 75883950.58194971,  75883967.85142569,  75883984.88147645,
         75884002.17728971,  75884019.37146682,  75884036.38934232],
       [ 75883944.42242044,  75883961.59666157,  75883978.6989056 ,
         75883995.8716574 ,  75884013.03561927,  75884030.17330837],
       [ 75883938.34911239,  75883955.44135804,  75883972.67638692,
         75883989.70197628,  75884006.75642563,  75884023.99312629]])
```

Comment: Have you tried mapping the time-zones to latitude / longitude first and then checking if the points are in a particular polygon?

Comment: @sophoros I am not sure what you mean by mapping the time zones, but I know the satellite trajectory if that helps (see recently attached image)

Comment: Time-zones' boundaries have specific latitude and longitude. Find a source of this information and use it to figure out the time-zone.